# Geometry Nodes: How to Make Randomly Varying Offsets in Mesh Line?

Tags: geometry-nodes

This works so-and-so, but not perfectly.

[image]

What I want is to add a new line section with every new iteration, in 1-3 meter line lengths randomly. But now they increase the line length overboard as I up the iteration.

[image]

How would you optimize this node graph and make it work as it should? I still don't have internalized how Repeat Zone should be used :/

[image]

Comment: Remember the title of your question should be specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I admit, I was having a difficult time with coming up the title, that edit you made taught me a lesson, yes

Comment: Note Though That Putting Too Many Capitalized Letters In A Sentence Hurts The Reading Comprehension. I've been guilty of that, too. ;)

Comment: @Gorgious I'm not a native English speaker, I thought it's just the way it goes in this language... :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iteratively extrude like so:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nicely optimized! Do they keep their positions if you go through iterations?

Comment: @ManuJärvinen yes because it's just extruding the last point

Answer (score 4):

Ooooh! I think I got it! I used 'Curve Length'!

[image]

[image]